# How to give the link dynamically for compare products in Opencart 2.x?

Tags: opencart2.x

I have made a custom bar in header section in opencart 2.1.0.1. Shown in the figure [Header custom bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRbDy.png).

Where I want to give a link to view compared products.
I know that "$compare" is the variable to get the path. I wanted to access "$compare" but it is giving the following error

"*Undefined variable compare in ..../header.tpl in line 68*"

How to give the link dynamically for compare products ?

Suggestion and Solutions are appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for this you need to modify header controller as well

```
$data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');
```

Put this line to your header controller than **$compare** will work on header.tpl